What's going on with my Gas Fireplace?
I have reviewed all similar questions but stumped. We will turn our gas fireplace on, everything works fine. But once we hit perhaps 1-2 hrs of usage, the pilot light stays lit but all the flames essentially go low or disappear. Why is this happening? Is gas leaking into our home?

and then after a while you can turn it on again ?

Yes with no problem

Is there a thermostat that controls the heat?  Make and model of the fireplace will help.

Have you measured how soon after going out it can be turned on again? Is the time delay consistent? When a heating appliance turns off unexpectedly, then works again later, my first thought is there's a thermal cutoff - a safety switch, perhaps. Look in the area around the gas valve; if you can find a wiring diagram for the fireplace controls, please add a picture of it.

is this a new behavior?

Heat n glo model SL-36 gdv is the make and model. Now it won't expand the flames at all when we turn on the switch. The pilot light stays on and has never gone out but when we switch it on, the flame does not expand to the entire fireplace. Could it be the ignitor?
